# Close infowindow when mouseout

Tags: google-maps, vuejs2, infowindow

How can I hide the infowindow when I leave it? I want to be able to hide it as soon as the mouse leaves the infowindow. I am using this vue package here: https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/issues/428

I tried it with something like this:

```
this.$nextTick(function() {
  self.$refs.gmap.$mapPromise.then(function(map){ // ensures that map 
                                                  object is ready and exists
    google.maps.event.addListener(self.infoWindow, 'mouseout', // self.infoWindow is infoWindow instance, 
                                                                  I am only using one and change content
    function(){
      self.infoWindow.infoWinOpen = false; // way of vue-google-maps 
                                              to close 
                                              infowindow
    });
  });
});
```

This doesn't work, when I try to apply it directly to the marker instead it only applies to the marker when I mouseout but not to the infowindow, that means that as soon as I leave the marker and want to move to the infowindow, the infowindow closes. Can anyone tell me how to close the infowindow as soon as I leave with the mouse out of the window?

Comment: so when you add this eventListener does the infowindow already exist?
I seems to me that it isn't available when registering the listener
Could you please add an jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to hide when the mouse leaves it, just add a `@mouseleave` listener to the element.

Is that what you're trying to do?

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/x84733/pen/GGYwEg?editors=1010

```
<div @mouseleave="hide = true" v-if="hide == false"></div>

...

data: () => ({
  hide: false
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle! It helped me! I was hung up on trying to solve the issue with the vue-google-maps methods itself instead of simply using this <div @mouseleave="hide = true" v-if="hide == false"></div> in the infowindow content itself, thanks, it helped me :)

Comment: @Benny no problem! Glad I could help